# Is it possible for run NUnit against a specific (long) list of tests

Tags: nunit, nunit-console

I have a list of **several thousand NUnit tests** that I want to run (generated automatically by another tool). (This is a subset of all of the tests, and changes frequently)

I'd like to be able to run these via NUnit-Console.exe. **Unfortunately the /run option only takes a direct list of files which in my case would not fit on a single command line. I'd like it to pickup the list from a filename.**

I appreciate that I could use categories, but the list I want to run changes frequently and so I'd prefer not to have to start changing source code.

Does anyone know if there is a clean way to get NUnit to run my specified tests?
(I could break it down into a series of smaller calls to NUnit-console with a full command line, but that's not very elegant)

(If it's not possible, maybe I should add it as an NUnit feature request.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had a reply from Charlie Poole (from NUnit development team), that this is not currently possible but has been added as a feature request for NUnit 2.6

Comment: Which has now been implemented, see: http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.2

Syntax: nunit-console /runlist:testlist.txt nunit.tests.dll

Comment: AndyM, What do you write in the text file though? I tried writing the name of the test cases but it doesn't work for me. Should I specify the path as well?

Comment: @KalaJ nunit-console.exe mytest.dll /runlist:c:\temp\tests.txt
tests.txt content: One line per test e.g.
mynamespace.subnamespace.class.methodname
If unsure, open the Nunit GUI and look at the properties of the test. Click on full name and copy/paster into your text file.

Answer (score 1):

I see what you're saying, but like you say you can run a single fixture from the command line.

```
nunit-console /fixture:namespace.fixture tests.dll
```

How about generating all the tests in the same fixture? Or place them all in the same assembly?

```
nunit-console tests.dll
```

Comment: Please note that as of [version 2.6.1](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.1) the `/fixture` switch has been deprecated. Please use `/run` or `/runlist` starting with that version.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [nunitLink](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.6.2), we need to mention the scenario/test case name. It simple but it has bit of a trick in it. Directly mentioning the test case name will not serve the purpose and you will end up with the 0 testcases executed. We need to write the exact path for the same.

I don't know how it works for other languages but using c# I have found a solution. Whenever we create a feature file corresponding feature.cs file get's created in Visual Studio. Click on the featureFileName.feature.cs and look for namespace and keep it aside(Part 1)

```
namespace MMBank.Test.Features
```

Scroll a bit down you will get the class name. Note that as well and keep it aside(Part 2)

```
public partial class HistoricalTransactionFeature
```

Keep scrolling down, you will see the code which nunit understands for execution basically.

```
[NUnit.Framework.TestAttribute()]
[NUnit.Framework.DescriptionAttribute("TC_1_A B C D")]
[NUnit.Framework.CategoryAttribute("MM_Bank")]
```

Below the code you can see the function/method name which will most likely be TC_1_ABCD(certain parameters)

```
public virtual void TC_1_ABCD(string username, string password, string visit)
```

You will be having multiple such methods based on no. of scenarios you have in your feature file. Note the method(test case) which you want to execute and keep it aside(Part 3)

Now collate all the parts with dots. Finally you will land up with something like this,

```
MMBank.Test.Features.HistoricalTransactionFeature.TC_1_ABCD
```

This is it. Similarly you can create the test case names from multiple feature files and stack them up in text file. Every test case name should be in different line. For command you can browse through above nunit link for execution using command prompt.